# How can be a JSP ".tag" file documented?

Tags: java, jsp, tag-library-descriptor

There is a JSP Tag file like this:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<%@ attribute name="attr" required="true" type="java.lang.String" rtexprvalue="true" description="FOOO" %>

<%@ attribute name="var" required="true" type="java.lang.String" rtexprvalue="false" description="BAAR" %>
<%@ variable name-from-attribute="var" variable-class="java.lang.String" alias="attrValue" scope="AT_BEGIN" %>

<c:set var="attrValue" value="${requestScope[attr]}" />
```

It seems to be possible to document the attributes. How to add documentation to the tag itself?

Comment: You have to describe it in the tag library descriptor: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnamu.html

Comment: @JozefChocholacek write an answer, and I accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper place to describe a tag and its properties (including attributes) is the [Tag Library Descriptor](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnamu.html). The `description` attribute of the `attribute` directive is IMHO a left-over "from the dark past" and does not have any real use nowadays.